# Running cucumber test in parallel

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have multiple cucumber features that I want to run.
The steps are spread across multiple classes , and they share common data between then for this purpose we use dependency injection (pico-container) , we share the driver object and data using this method
I understand that because of the pico container we cannot run test in parallel as it will mess up the execution.
I want to know if there is any other way to run test in parallel in this approach.

Project arch :

1. Package : Feature file : This includes all the feature file.
2. Package : StepDefination : This includes multiple class and step
   definitions are split in those
   classes based on the microservices they interact
   This also include the scenarioContext class that we use the share
   data.
3. Package : Runner class : This includes the runner class with features parameter pointing to the
   feature package

Please throw your ideas on my problem here.

Comment: If you don't share data between scenarios or use static variables it will work fine. Have you tried?

Comment: I understand static , but what do you mean by do not share data between scenario. I need to share data between steps that belong to same scenario , no sharing of data is happening between different scenario.

Comment: Some people have scenario A and then continue where scenario A stopped with scenario B. That doesn't work with parallel execution. So if you don't do that, you're good.

Comment: What you've described in your question is exactly how to run scenarios in parallel. So I don't understand why you think it won't work.

Comment: Then it should work ,I will try it thank you for your inputs